# How to migrate from UserService & User to custom authentication system?

Tags: java, authentication, google-app-engine

I have thousands of users, and millions of datastore entities (and their indexes) which have `User` fields. I'd like to migrate to a custom authentication system, and completely abandon `UserService`. However, I'd rather not have to run a massive database schema update.

Can I re-use the `User` class, so I don't need to change my datastore schema? Or will that cause immediate or long-term problems?

Comment: Thousands is not a massive database update.

Comment: @PeterKnego i have millions of entities that refer to those thousands of User objects